# Why is /proc/meminfo reporting misleading SwapTotal after suspends

Tags: linux, monitoring, swap, suspend

Consider this:

```
[skrat@apex geri]$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep SwapTotal
SwapTotal:      18438120 kB

[skrat@apex geri]$ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (deleted)                partition       3073020 0       10
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (deleted)                partition       3073020 0       10
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (deleted)                partition       3073020 0       10
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (deleted)                partition       3073020 0       10
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (deleted)                partition       3073020 0       10
/dev/mmcblk0p2                          partition       3073020 583196  1000
```

Why is `meminfo` reporting total swap size including deleted swap files/devices? The reason it bothers me is that everytime the system gets suspended, these devices are remounted, every time adding new `(deleted)` swap device, adding up to misleding `SwapTotal` value. That makes it rather hard to monitor swap usage unless I'm willing to use parse and sum `swapon -s` output. How can I purge these `(deleted)` devices or get `SwapTotal` to report *good values*?

Comment: Does `free -m` show it correctly?

Comment: It doesn't, same numbers. Same goes for `top` and `htop`, they all use `meminfo`.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Alasdair G Kergon: If you deleted an active swap file it then became impossible to 'swapoff'. 2004, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.lvm.general/4949

If, each time you suspend your laptop, it is unloading the mmcblk driver, then this deletes an active swap device. Now it becomes impossible to swapoff. It does not prevent `swapon` to work once this device is recreated, but for linux it is a different device, not the same device.

You should tell you laptop to `swapoff /dev/mmcblk0p2` before each suspend. Either manually, before each suspend, or once for all in who knows which acpi script.